# Are there differences between the W.I.T.C.H. books and comics?

Tags: books, comics, w.i.t.c.h

I remember reading the *W.I.T.C.H.* magazines which had comics inside, but I also had big books with comics and little books that had comics parts and novel parts.

I would like to know the difference in the history between them or if the books are a recompilation of the comics.